# .exe made by Pyinstaller isn't recognizing a module. The module in question was defined in the main file

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller, libraries

Not sure if it is relevant but I am using pycharm.
[This is how my main file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBcZz.png)
[How my total directory looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJkK.png)

When the CMD is turned on, the app crashes without and warning errors, when it is turned off it can't find the python application one file. I'm really not sure what I should try from here.

edit: the code was ran in the pycharm shell.
edit: It looks like the star declaration might be the cause, does anyone have any suggestions of what I can replace the star with?
edit: the pyApplication uses also uses the cooking module

Comment: replace it with whatever it is that you need in that module '

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: Within that module, it also uses the asterisk. will that need to be replaced as well?

Comment: from kivy.app import App
from PythonApplication1 import *
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from cooking import *
from googleDrive import *